# View file structure of my Azure Linux VM

Tags: linux, azure, prestashop

I'm new to Azure; I wanted to take advantage of being able [to run PrestaShop](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/prestashop.prestashop?tab=Overview) (e-commerce software) and Azure marketplace has single VM plan. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qGZhQxbM7c) and got it up and running. Trouble is to login to the site's Admin interface you need to know the [secret folder that is randomly created](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Connecting+to+the+PrestaShop+back+office) by the installer. I have tried the Azure Storage Explorer [image: Azure Explorer], but nothing useful is displayed. I also tried to login using putty and SSH, but keep getting access denied. I suspect I need to configure an endpoint for port 22, [as described here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2013/11/12/running-a-remote-desktop-on-a-windows-azure-linux-vm/) in order to get ftp working, but apparently this is not possible with a free subscription (?).

Any help as to how I can find that folder name would be appreciated.

Comment: You're looking at blob storage, which is not the vm's file system. Just ssh to the vm. FYI this type of question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: By default, you should use VM's account and password to login this VM and check the file system, after you login this VM, try to switch to root and check it again.

Answer (score -1):

With Azure Free Trial Subscription, I can successfully login into the PrestaShop Azure Linux VM without any issue.

**Note:** No need to configure an endpoint for port 22.

To connect to your Linux virtual machine using SSH, use the following command: **ssh username@IPAddress** and password.

If you are facing an issue with your login, you can reset the password.